# How does Visual Studio 2012 embed manifest with default settings for my .csproj

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, embedded-resource

I'm trying this again, since yesterday my question drew no attention, and I'm guessing it was due to the lack of a well worded explanation.

When I build my WPF application, with the "Embed manifest with default settings" option checked, my `AssemblyInfo.cs` version info is embedded inside the output `.EXE`, and right-clicking the `.EXE` and checking properties shows that.  I'm wondering how and at what point, does the compiler embed that data into my `.EXE`?

I ask because I recently had to create my own `.res` file to embed multiple icons into my .EXE with appropriate indexes.  The problem with that is you need to select the "Resource File" instead of "Embed manifest with default settings option;" so you lose your AssemblyInfo version information and have to update and rebuild your `.res` file every time you do a release.

In short, I'm trying to find a way to compile my own `.res` file that uses my `AssemblyInfo.cs` version information and is automatically embedded for every build (my versions contain `*` definitions), so I don't have to worry about remembering to update my .rc and compile for the .res.

Comment: It is a long answer that will not in any way help you solve your problem.  Avoid asking XY questions.

Comment: @HansPassant Then its not really an answer is it? Your answer regarding how to create a .res file is what I used to customize mine.  Is there really no way to get current assembly info into the .res? If VS2012 embeds the AssemblyInfo, shouldn't there be a way to specify icons too?